# Automorphism of $U(16)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I wanted to find Automorphism group of $U(16)$.
I know that $U(16) \approx  Z_2 \times Z_4$ .Which is not cyclic. Actually I can give automorphism in case of cyclic group using generator of that group as possible image of $\phi (1)$ where $\phi$ is automorphism .But in case of non cyclic group I am not able to write solution ?